# My VBA code crashes when i try to set the variable to a specific rule

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

```
Sub RunRuleMyRule()
    Dim myRule As Outlook.Rules
    Dim theRule As Outlook.Rule
    Set myRule = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
    Set theRule = myRules.Item("rule1") 'get error here
    If theRule.Enabled Then
        theRule.Execute
    Else
        theRule.Enabled = True
        theRule.Execute
    End If
End Sub
```

When I debug it, theRule is "Nothing" and my code crashes. I am not sure what else can be done. I know the rule exists on the client and I've run the rule manually.

Answer (score 0):

At least to prevent crashing (I don't know why the rule cannot be found when you say it exists), try:

```
Set theRule = myRules.Item("rule1") 
If (theRule Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870173(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Rules class obtains a Rule object specified by Index, which is either a numerical index into the Rules collection or the rule name.

Most probably you pass a wrong value to the method. Try to iterate over all rules and check their names to be sure such rule exists.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: When I do this, it worked Session.DefaultStore.GetRules().Item("rule1").Execute . Is there a way to run rules on a specific "Shared" mailbox or mails within the last 2 weeks?

Comment: You may check it in the VBA code and process the message further or just return the control flow (don't do anything).